# Slow Javascript Performance of a .NET Core MVC Project on localhost in VS 2017

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, localhost, iis-express

**Introduction:**

I am developing a strategy game based on .NET Core MVC. The main part of the game is written in Javascript and therefore executed on client side.

The most computing-intensive part is the constant redrawing of the "game map" on a CANVAS, especially when you navigate through the map. It has to check a lot of objects (Buildings, Tiles, etc.) in array on every keystroke (W, A, S, D).

**Small extract from the code, so you get the idea:**

```
render();
requestAnimFrame(main);

function render() {
    renderMapBuildings() 
}

function renderMapBuildings(list) {
    //var count = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if ((list[i].pos[1] + camera.pos[1]) < CANVAS_HEIGHT && (list[i].pos[0] + camera.pos[0]) < CANVAS_WIDTH && (list[i].pos[1] + camera.pos[1]) > -60 && (list[i].pos[0] + camera.pos[0]) > -60) {               
            if (list[i].id == Building.Current.id && list[i].type == 1)
                ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
            //count++;
            renderEntity(list[i]);  
            ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
        }
    }
    //console.log("mapbuildings_new length: " + count);
}

function renderEntity(entity) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(entity.pos[0] + camera.pos[0], entity.pos[1] + camera.pos[1]);
    entity.sprite.render(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that the javascript part gets very slow, when I run the game on localhost with Visual Studio 2017 on IIS Express. The above code is executed much slower and it begins to stutter. It's very annoying developing like this.

The strange part is, it works flawless online. The intense Javascript code is executed very fast. It is published on a Linux VPS with ReverseProxy.

*Do you have any idea, why there is such a huge difference between Localhost Development and the published application?*

some additional infos:

- serverside code isn't a problem, there is also no SQL Call made during the "lag".
- I've already created a new user profile and reinstalled VS 2017
- I tried two different Computers (both Windows 10).
- I disabled Javascript Debugging.

Comment: Your web browser is the key right now for you to verify JavaScript performance, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/ I doubt it is a server side issue.

Comment: Optimizing the performance of my JavasScript code is definitely something I need to do, thanks for the link. Will dig through it! Though I don' understand, how there is such a performance difference between the local server (iis express) and the online environment (Kestrel-Server on Linux). Even if I open it in the same browser in different tabs, I can notice the striking difference, So I doubt it's just about the code?

Comment: Are you making AJAX requests? That's the only thing I can think of that would definitely stall performance only locally, as IIS Express is a single-threaded web server. In other words, it can only handle one request at a time, so if you're firing off a bunch of AJAX requests in quick succession, they're going to start getting backed up in the queue. Whereas on full IIS, you can handle roughly 1000 simultaneous requests without doing anything special, and many more if configured right.

Comment: I am doing AJAX requests, but not during navigating through the map where the problem actually appears. It doesn't communicate with the server at all during the lag.

Comment: Have you opened the network console before the lag? Just to be sure. Because, if the browser is the same.. there is not much places to look for the problem.

Comment: Just to check, how did you go about disabling JS debugging?

Comment: @Emeeus : Yes, the page has been loaded completely. As I mentioned, The lag appears during the navigating (see executed code above), so there isn't any network activity

Comment: @BenSmith : I just disabled JS Debugging in Visual studio (Tools / Debugging)

Comment: Is it the same using local IIS and not IIS express?

Comment: Take a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/. It can be the point.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from to draw the map as it moves? That will, most likely, be what is slowing it down. We can't really answer this, as you're not showing what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @itdoesntwork Nice input, I've now installed IIS local and tried it, but unfortunately the same effect occurs

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes, you're totally right, but it's almost impossible to set up an environment where you can check it yourself. There are so many dependencies and I don't want to provide the entire source code. The data is initially loaded by AJAX and stored in JS Arrays. I probably will try to change the rendering code from Canvas to WebGL..

Comment: Did you use the same publish configuration?

Comment: @itdoesntwork Yeah, I have tried using the same configuration "release". Same effect appears..